# How to save user login credentials using PhoneGap API?

Tags: iphone, cordova, sencha-touch, autologin

I want to save user login credential in my iPhone app, The app is build using PhoneGap and SenchaTouch API's. If the user login through the App, I want to save his userId/Password unless and until he specifically logout. This will save him from login process every time he uses the app and add to user experience.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is always localStorage. It is a simple key / value persistence that will do exactly what you are looking for.

http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/

edit: The above link died: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: and PhoneGap localStorage examples at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: Yeah, if your persistence needs expand beyond key/value stuff... there is PhoneGaps Storage API using web SQL

Comment: What about the security issues involved?

Comment: The localStorage DB is protected by the app sandbox / permissions... however, the security issue arises if the phone is lost or stolen. Under these conditions (along with say rooting an Android device or JailBreaking an iOS one) an attacker could get ahold of the localStorage DB. One option on iOS is the KeyChain, but there is no equivalent on Android and even the KeyChain is only secure if the user 's device is locked with a PIN.

Comment: @Devgeeks the link posted on the original answer is broken, as of now. Can you please bear the pain of adding a working link once more..or tell, how to use this link

Comment: I have added a new link with a decent description of the options and apis.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it in one of my project :

```
var login = this.loginField.getValue(),
    pwd = this.passwordField.getValue(),    
    logChain = login + ":" + pwd,
    logChain64 = Ext.util.base64.encode(logChain);

window.localStorage.setItem("YOUR_APP_credentials", logChain64);
```

Comment: Why bother base64 encoding it?

Comment: In case the phone is stolen/hacked?

Comment: Just to be clear, base64 is no encryption. It transfers binary data to text to transport it across domains and such without it being modified. It has absolutely no extra value when your phone is stolen, hacked, ...

Comment: It could confuse the less intelligent phone thieves out there... :D

Comment: You would NEVER persist the users password! Generate a token from the user and password and save the token+username to gain access.